# How to flushbottom in the middle of a page respective to the next page

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, double-sided

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{mm}
\begin{document}
\newbox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\section{foobar}\lipsum[3-5]\end{minipage}}
\newlength{\myheight}
\settototalheight{\myheight}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}[t][\myheight]{\textwidth}
\section{foo}
\lipsum[1]

\vfill

\section{bar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\clearpage%
\usebox{\mybox}

\printlength{\myheight}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the second part of the first page to be shifted down, so that its bottom aligns to the bottom of the text on the next page. I tried to measure that text's height and set a minipage of the same height. But as you can see, the height isn't calculated correctly.

How can I make LaTeX do the thing I want? (I do realize the numbering of the sections is in wrong order by this method, but that is of no importance for my real document.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to show how to fix it than explain why it fails, which would require looking into exactly how `\settototalheight` works.  It is generally safer to expand `\usebox{\mybox}` than just `\mybox` (which deletes the contents, at least locally).

Since you have glue inside the `minipage`, you might as well use `[s]`.  The difference is that the default effectively adds a `\vfil` above and below, which is overpowered by the `\vfill`.

It should be noted that any global definitions or modifications inside a `\savebox` will take place immediately, so you need to futz with the section counter to get it right.

The following is sort of a minimal modification.  The only style change was moving some definitions to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{mm}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\myheight}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}%
\savebox{\mybox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \section{foobar}\lipsum[3-5]
  \end{minipage}}
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\settototalheight{\myheight}{\usebox{\mybox}}
\begin{minipage}[c][\myheight][s]{\textwidth}
\section{foo}
\lipsum[1]

\vfill

\section{bar}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\clearpage%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\usebox{\mybox}

\printlength{\myheight}
\end{document}
```

The following is how I would have done it.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{mm}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\myheight}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}%
\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\section{foobar}\lipsum[3-5]}
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\setlength{\myheight}{\dimexpr \ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}
\vbox to \myheight{%
\section{foo}
\lipsum[1]

\vfill

\section{bar}
\lipsum[2]}
\clearpage%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\usebox{\mybox}

\printlength{\myheight}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, the only relevant differences I see are: 1. The use of `\usebox` in `\settototalheight`. 2. The use of the third optional parameter `s` in `minipage`-environment.

Comment: The use of [s] is optional, so long as you use \vfill instead of \vfil.